# Best way to get multiple values from dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dict objects like this:

```
[{'emailAddress': 'user1@example.com', 'country': 'US'},
{'emailAddress': 'user2@example.com', 'country': 'CA'},
{'emailAddress': 'user3@example.com', 'country': 'UK'}]
```

The list of dict objects is just over 200k records long.

What I'd like to do is find the country for a list of email addresses.  For example, if I have a list like this:

```
['user1@example.com', 'user3@example.com']
```

I'd like it to return this:

```
['US', 'UK']
```

Now I can do this by defining a function like this:

```
def getBaseOUs(emailAddresses):
    countries = []
    for emailAddress in emailAddresses:
        for user in usermap:
            if emailAddresses == user['emailAddress']:
                countries.append(user['country'])
    return countries
```

But am wondering what people think the fastest / most cpu efficient way of doing this would be?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason to use a list of dicts, or can you convert it to a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: No reason - list of dicts is just what I'm familiar with.  I can convert it to anything necessary.

Comment: Assuming email addresses are unique (ie an email address is associated with a single country) you can use the email address as key and country as value in a single dictionary, giving you O(1) (on avg) lookup time instead of iterating through a 200K-elements list.

Comment: Yes, the 200k email addresses are unique.

Comment: @Michael so dump the list and use the email as a key.

Comment: Gotcha, so when I build the list make it look like [{'user1@example.com': 'US'}, {'user2@example.com': 'CA'}].  That does seem much better.

Comment: @Michael No, you still have a list of dicts. Consider `{'user1@example.com': 'US', 'user2@example.com': 'CA'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@deepspace pointed out that I don't need a list of dicts.  A single dict will do:

```
{'user1@example.com': 'US', 'user2@example.com': 'CA'}
```

Then I can simply get the country(s) with the key(s).  This performs pretty quick with ~500k items.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely your best bet if you want to query approximately as many email addresses as you have users

```
database = [{'emailAddress': 'user1@example.com', 'country': 'US'},
{'emailAddress': 'user2@example.com', 'country': 'CA'},
{'emailAddress': 'user3@example.com', 'country': 'UK'}]

emails = ['user1@example.com', 'user3@example.com']
emailset = set(emails)

countries = [record['country'] for record in database if record['emailAddress'] in emailset]
```

On the other hand, if you're only ever going to query a small subset of the users:

```
def query(database, emails):
    answer = []
    emailset = set(emails)
    for record in database:
        if not emailset: break
        email = record['emailAddress']
        if email not in emailSet: continue
        emailSet.pop(email)
        answer.append(record['country'])

    return answer
```

Of course, the best overall solution would be to create a single dictionary mapping emails to the dictionaries you currently have:

```
def transform(database):
    answer = {}
    for record in database:
        answer[record]['emailAddress'] = record
    return answer
```

Now, you can query it like this:

```
def query(database, emails):
    database = transform(database)
    answer = [database[email] for email in emails]
    return answer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(addresses)
df = df.set_index('emailAddress')
result = df.loc[somelist]['country']
for i in result:
    print(i)
# US
# UK
```

The dataframe should also take up less space than your list of dicts, and by making email the index, it's O(1) for each lookup.

EDIT: DeepSpace makes a good point. To reduce the footprint, you can delete the original dict:

```
del addresses
```

Though if you can help it, just use the more compact Pandas dataframe from the start, without creating the dict.

Comment: "The dataframe should also take up less space than your list of dicts." Why would it?

Comment: Dicts allocate room for the hash table, rather than just pointers to each entry. A more direct approach is your O(1) dict of email: user, which can also be achieved in Pandas by setting email as the index.

Comment: Alright, but the dict is already in memory by the time the code runs. So now there is both the dict and the dataframe in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going through every user for every e-mail address, make a lookup of users by e-mail address:

```
def get_email_lookup(users):
    return {user['emailAddress']: user for user in users}
```

and then make use of it:

```
def getBaseOUs(emailAddresses):
    by_email = get_email_lookup(usermap)
    return [by_email[email]['country'] for email in emailAddresses]
```